# Tamiya Dual Gearbox attached to an Arduino Uno Board

Tags: arduino, motor, stepper-motor

I'm building a robot that uses the arduino uno microcontroller, and the tracks system is run by the [tamiya 70168-Double-Gearbox-Kit](http://www.tamiya.com/english/products/70168double_gearbox/index.htm).

Each Tamiya motor only uses 3V which is fine but it seems the stepper will help to control speed and direction of the motors. Does the Arduino Uno Microcontroller not allow you to control speed and direction?

Do I need a stepper to have control of the tamiya gearbox?

Comment: what do you men by stepper? A Step-down board to power the motor ?

Comment: what does this mean? ... `Do I need a stepper to have control of the tamiya gearbox?` ..... the gearbox has DC motors built in .... there appears to be no control mechanism that you could operate with a stepper motor

Answer (score 1):

You can not plus the motors T130 motors directly to your arduino because of the current they require.  [These motors](https://www.pololu.com/product/77)  need up to 2.1 A, which you can not get directly from the arduino.

The motors need to be plug to the battery via an adequate motor driver (common electronics board). And the arduino needs to be connected to the motor driver, to send the commands tot he motor driver.

If you want precise control of the speed you also need to have encoders to get information about the output shaft speed and do a control loop (like PID) in the arduino.